# Present value of a cashflow with constant interest

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

Consider the effective annual rate of interest to be $18%$ for this question.

A man invests in a structured note and will receive bonus payouts of $300$, $400$, $500$ at the beginning of the first,third and fifth year respectively.

(i) At which point in time will a single payout of $1200$ be equivalent to these bonus payouts? Give your answer to the nearest $o.1$ year.

(ii) What is the future value, to the nearest dollar, of these payouts at the end of the tenth year?

---

Solution

(i)

$1200(1.18)^t=300+400(1.18)^3+500(1.18)^5$

Solving for $t$, $t=4.9$

For (ii), I do not understand how I should proceed

Comment: This question makes no sense. You refer to payments being made in *weeks* yet use an *annual* interest to discount these payments?

Comment: I corrected it, Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (ii), add up the future values until $t=10$ for each payout to get
$$300(1.18)^9+400(1.18)^7+500(1.18)^5$$
Alternatively, using (i), you might compute the future value of $1200(1.18)^{4.9}$ over the remaining time until $t=10$: 
$$1200(1.18)^{4.9}(1.18)^{10-4.9}$$